# Mosquitto broker and TLS configuration

Tags: ssl, mqtt, tls1.2, mosquitto

I am trying to configure the MQTT Mosquitto broker with TLS.
After following the mosquitto manual, I've edited the `mosquitto.conf` as bellow

```
# Place your local configuration in /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/
#
# A full description of the configuration file is at
# /usr/share/doc/mosquitto/examples/mosquitto.conf.example

pid_file /run/mosquitto/mosquitto.pid
persistence true
persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/
log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log
include_dir /etc/mosquitto/conf.d

listener  8883

cafile /home/openest/certs/ca/ca.crt
certfile /home/openest/certs/broker/broker.crt
keyfile /home/openest/certs/broker/broker.key
require_certificate true
```

The problem is when I am restarting the mosquitto broker, I am getting this error

```
Job for mosquitto.service failed because the control process exited with error code.                                        
See "systemctl status mosquitto.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

This is the output when I run `systemctl status mosquitto.service`

```
● mosquitto.service - Mosquitto MQTT Broker
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mosquitto.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2022-04-11 15:25:56 CEST; 1min 22s ago
       Docs: man:mosquitto.conf(5)
             man:mosquitto(8)
    Process: 2384 ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -m 740 -p /var/log/mosquitto (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 2385 ExecStartPre=/bin/chown mosquitto /var/log/mosquitto (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 2386 ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -m 740 -p /run/mosquitto (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 2387 ExecStartPre=/bin/chown mosquitto /run/mosquitto (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 2388 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mosquitto -c /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 2388 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 6ms
```

This is the output of `journalctl -xe`

```
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░
░░ A start job for unit mosquitto.service has finished with a failure.
░░
░░ The job identifier is 4473 and the job result is failed.
Apr 12 10:15:12 debian systemd[1]: mosquitto.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
░░ Subject: Automatic restarting of a unit has been scheduled
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░
░░ Automatic restarting of the unit mosquitto.service has been scheduled, as the result for
░░ the configured Restart= setting for the unit.
Apr 12 10:15:12 debian systemd[1]: Stopped Mosquitto MQTT Broker.
░░ Subject: A stop job for unit mosquitto.service has finished
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░
░░ A stop job for unit mosquitto.service has finished.
░░
░░ The job identifier is 4545 and the job result is done.
Apr 12 10:15:12 debian systemd[1]: mosquitto.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Apr 12 10:15:12 debian systemd[1]: mosquitto.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
░░ Subject: Unit failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░
░░ The unit mosquitto.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 12 10:15:12 debian systemd[1]: Failed to start Mosquitto MQTT Broker.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit mosquitto.service has failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░
░░ A start job for unit mosquitto.service has finished with a failure.
░░
░░ The job identifier is 4545 and the job result is failed.
Apr 12 10:15:22 debian sudo[3055]:   chaima : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/chaima ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/journalctl -xe
Apr 12 10:15:22 debian sudo[3055]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by chaima(uid=1000)
```

Note that I've also opened up the port `8883` in the fire wall by running:

```
sudo ufw allow 8883
Rules updated
Rules updated (v6)
```

Do you have any idea about how I can fix this error please and thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the output of the 2 commands that the error **tells** you to run? Also does your `mosquitto.conf` really start with "  GNU nano 5.4              /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf" ?

Comment: The error message listed 2 commands, we need to see both of them.

Comment: What output do you get when you manually run `sudo /usr/sbin/mosquitto -c -v /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf`? What does the Mosquitto log file show?

Comment: @romkey I'd rather see the `journalctl` output rather than debug the file permission problems when it can't open the log file...

Comment: @hardlib I'd definitely prioritize your questions :)

Comment: Oh sorry @hardillb I thought that I've written the `journalctl -exe` output !. I've updated the question

Comment: You need to run `journalctl -xe` straight after it fails to start (`sudo service mosquitto start`) for it to be useful.

Comment: And it needs to be run with `sudo` (see the first line of the output "You are currently not seeing messages from other users and the system."

Answer (score 1):

OK, we are not getting what we need from the `sudo journalctl -xe` (most likely because not enough scrollback has been presented to show the first failure).

The most likely reason is that the `mosquitto` user does not have access to the cert/keys you have configured.

Move these files to `/etc/mosquitto` and make sure the files are owned by the `mosquitto` user.

Comment: I've tried it but I am getting the same error message again

Comment: run `sudo service mosquitto stop` wait 5 minutes, then run `sudo service mosquitto start` and when that fails run the `sudo journalctl -xe` again. You are looking for the entries that different to what you posted earlier (also check in `/var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log`). Failing that try running `sudo mosquitto -v -c /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf` and check the output